# Reading a ranges iterator in C++; getting ASAN error

Tags: c++, c++20

I get an ASAN error (AddressSanitizer: stack-use-after-scope READ error.) in the following code.

```cpp
std::string aS = “hello how”;
std::string bS = “are you”;
std::string cS = “doing today”;

folly::small_vector<folly::StringPiece, 4> aVec;
folly::splitTo<folly::StringPiece>(" ", aS, std::back_inserter(aVec));
folly::small_vector<folly::StringPiece, 4> bVec;
folly::splitTo<folly::StringPiece>(" ", bS, std::back_inserter(bVec));
folly::small_vector<folly::StringPiece, 4> cVec;
folly::splitTo<folly::StringPiece>(" ", cS, std::back_inserter(cVec));

for (const auto& [a, b, c] :
           ranges::views::zip(aVec, bVec, cVec)) {
        if (a == "hello") { // ==> asan error here
          fn(a,b,c);
        }
}

void fn(std::string a, std::string b, std::string c)
{
// do something
}
```

I am trying to understand why I am seeing the ASAN error.
What is the type for a,b,c here?
How can I initialize a string from it?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: What is the type of `ranges::view::all_t<folly::small_vector<folly::StringPiece, 4>>`?  zip's behaviour is very different depending on that.  (`a` `b` and `c` are going to be `folly::StringPiece`s assuming folly smallvec isn't insane.).  I'm also a bit scared of your `for(:)` loop not **exactly** matching the code that you are seeing the ASAN error on; seemingly innocuous changes there could explain it.

Comment: /cc @Yakk-AdamNevraumont This checks out fine under valgrind, asan and ubsan for me: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/vyK5pyK2Sc/. Output `a:hello b:are c:doing\na:how b:you c:today\n`

Comment: @sehe as a eduguess, aVec/bVec/cVec are actuslly returned from some function instead of being local variabbles, or something of that nature.  And the zip view stores references to dangling temporaries.

Comment: aVec/bVec/cVec are local variables , initialized using string obtained from other function. Can a reference to folly::StringPiece be compared to string literal that way using "==". When I replaced folly::StringPiece with std::string, the asan error goes away.